# Corona SDK / Lua : An table's property is nil, when accessed via event.other during collision event. But why?

Tags: lua, null, coronasdk, collision

So I have this module, where all of its activity during the game is in. In `t.physics` I add a collision event listener (differentiating if target is a group or a single object). When the concerning objects detect a collision though, the property `col` of the other object (`event.other`) seems to be `nil`, although I initially set it to a string representing a color in `t.create`. I just can't find the cause for that, can anyone?

Thanks for your help.
Greetings, Nils

```
local fence = require("lib.fence")
local physics = require("physics")
local t = {}
    local stages = {yellow = 1, lila = 1, red = 1}
    local sizes = {1, 3.625, 7.25}
    t.colors = {"yellow", "lila", "red"}
    t.growing = false

    t.setSize = function(fill)
        local tHeight = fill.contentHeight * sizes[stages[fill.col]]
        local tScale = tHeight / fill.contentHeight
        fill.yScale = tScale

    end

    t.grow = function(group, color, hero)
        local counter = 0
        stages[color] = stages[color] + 1
        for i = 1, group.numChildren, 1 do
            if group[i].col == color then
                counter = counter + 1
                local function newPhysics() t.physics(group) end
                if counter == 1 then
                    local function reset() t.growing = false if stages[color] == 3 then stages[color] = 1; newPhysics(); end end
                    local function start() t.growing = true end
                    transition.to(group[i], {time = 260, yScale = sizes[stages[color]], onStart = start, onComplete = reset})
                else
                    transition.to(group[i], {time = 250, yScale = sizes[stages[color]], onStart = start})
                end
            end
        end
    end

    t.physics = function(target)
        if target.numChildren == nil then
            physics.removeBody(target)
            local function add()
                physics.addBody( target, "static", {isSensor = true} )
                target.collision = function(self, event)
                    if event.phase == "began" then
                        target.count = target.count + 1
                        if target.count == 1 then
                            t.grow(target.parent, self.col, event.other)
                        end
                    elseif event.phase == "ended" then
                        target.count = 0
                    end
                end
            end
            timer.performWithDelay(1, add, 1)
        else
            for i = 1, target.numChildren, 1 do
                physics.removeBody( target[i] )
                physics.addBody( target[i], "static", {isSensor = true} )
                target[i].name = "fill"
                local fill = target[i]
                fill.count = 0
                fill.collision = function(self, event)
                    if event.phase == "began" then
                        self.count = self.count + 1
                        if self.count == 1 and event.other.x ~= nil then
                            t.grow(target, self.col, event.other)
                        end
                    else
                        fill.count = 0
                    end
                end
                fill:addEventListener("collision")
            end
        end
    end

    t.setColor = function(fill)
        local colors = {
            {238 / 255, 228 / 255, 28 / 255},
            {38 / 255, 33 / 255, 77 / 255},
            {175 / 255, 24 / 255, 52 / 255},
        }
        local names = {"yellow", "lila", "red"}
        local r = math.random(3)
        fill.fill = colors[r]
        fill.col = names[r]
    end

    t.create = function(fences, group, colors)
        local fills = {}
        for i = 1, #fences, 1 do
            local rCol = math.random(3)
            local col
            if rCol == 1 then
                col = colors.yellow
            elseif rCol == 2 then
                col = colors.lila
            else
                col = colors.red
            end
            fills[i] = display.newRect(
                group, fences[i].x + fences[i].contentWidth * 0.125, fences[i].y,
                fences[i].contentWidth * 0.9, (fences[i].contentHeight * 0.5 / 3)
            )
            fills[i].dPosX = fills[i].x
            fills[i].y = display.contentHeight- fills[i].contentHeight / 2
            fills[i].fill = col
            fills[i].col = t.colors[rCol]
            fills[i].increased = false
        end
        return fills
    end

    t.move = function(fills, fences, group)
        for i = 1, #fills, 1 do
            local fill = fills[i]
            function fill:enterFrame()
                self:translate(fence.speed, 0)
                if t.growing == false then
                    t.setSize(self)
                end
                if self.x > display.contentWidth + 0.55 * fences[i].contentWidth then
                    local xT = {}
                    for i = 1, group.numChildren, 1 do
                        xT[i] = group[i].x
                    end
                    local function compare(a, b) return a < b end
                    table.sort(xT, compare)
                    self.x = xT[1] - fences[i].contentWidth * 0.98
                    t.setColor(self)
                    local function newPhysics() t.physics(self) end
                    timer.performWithDelay( 25, newPhysics, 1 )
                    self:toBack()
                end
            end
            Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", fill)
        end
    end
return t
```

Comment: You are passing `event.other` as 3rd argument to function `t.grow`, but it is never used inside (its local name inside the function is `hero`).

Comment: Is `hero.col == nil` in `t.grow()`?

Comment: I explained the mistake in n answer. Also, sry, that I forgot to include the nil pointer, I unintentionally removed it before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Ugh, sorry, I forgot to define the property on the other object involved (hero), that has its own module. What a stupid slip.

Thanks for your answers anyways!

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  Could you also express your thanks by clicking the up arrow beside my answer :-)

Comment: Yes, I already did but it does not display due to my low reputation.

Comment: Thanks.  Don't worry.  You're rep will increase quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have any dynamic bodies here.  What is colliding with what?  Could it be that the other object involved in the collision (the value of `event.other`) is not something initialized in `t.create()` and so doesn't have the `col` property?

From the Corona documentation on [Collision Detection](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/physics/collisionDetection/index.html):

> Some body types will — or will not — collide with other body types. In a collision between two physical objects, at least one of the objects must be dynamic, since this is the only body type which collides with any other type.

Also, in your `fill.collision()`, I think you want to pass `event.target` as the first argument to `t.grow()` rather than target.  If you try things, please update the question with more information.

Comment: I explained the mistake in n answer. Also, sry, that I forgot to include the nil pointer, I unintentionally removed it before posting.

Comment: Also : hero is the dynamic body (other module).